# getblocktemplate not returning coinbasetxn

Tags: bitcoind

In a simple 3 node regtest mode setup getblocktemplate does not return 'coinbasetxn' even when passing in the capabilities string with coinbasetxn set.  I do get a coinbasevalue and coinbaseaux field.  What am I missing?